# Что такое проекционный редактор?

Tags: ide

Изучаю среду разработки Realaxy ActionScript Editor. В ней редактор именно такой. В чем преимущество такого редактора? Совершенно непонятно, зачем его сделали таким. И в чем принцип работы? Как устроен обычный редактор я примерно представляю: есть модель (данные, которые написал юзер), есть парсер, который влияет на отображение (подсветка синтаксиса, например).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если честно то Realaxy ActionScript Editor мне не совсем нравится. Я пытался год назад поставить его на свой комп, ничего не получилось, наверное за год они улучшили и исправили бага, но первое впечатление негативное. Лучше поставьте [fdt](http://fdt.powerflasher.com/) и не парьтесь, она есть в бесплатной версии.